# Normalizing a list of strings Python

Tags: python, string, normalization, data-cleaning

I have a very large list of strings which each words in the list are unnormalized, for instance:

```
word_list = ["Alzheimer", "Alzheimer's", "Alzheimer.", "Alzheimer?","Cognition.", "Cognition's", "Cognitions", "Cognition"] # and the list goes on
```

As you can see,there are many identical terms in the list but some of them contain unnecessary puntuations (e.g.: dot, single apostrophe), how can I make all the words normalize (e.g.: "Alzheimers." -> "Alzheimers", "Cognition's" -> "Cognition") ?

Thank you in advance!

I expect a function that to filter out unnecessary single punctuations, I tried the following function but it did not work well:

```
def word_normalizer(word): # Remove unnecessary single puntuations and turn all words into lower case
    puntuations = ["'", '"', ";", ":", ",", ".", "&", "(", ")"]
    new_word =""
    for punc in puntuations:
        if punc in word:
            new_word = word.strip(punc)
            
        return new_word.lower()
```

Comment: `word.strip(punc)` will only strip the punctuation character from the beginning or end of the input string. If you want to remove the punctuation from inside the word, you can use  `word.replace(punc, "")` instead.

Comment: `.strip()` only removes the characters from the start and end of the word. Additionally, the `return` is indented too deep.

Comment: and `return` should be indented one level to the left, outside of the loop

Comment: What do you want to happen with `"Cognitions", "Cognition"` ? Will they remain intact, or will the `s` be removed from the end of `"Cognitions"`

Comment: What you try to achieve may not be as immediate at it can appear at the first sight.
It is related to Natural Language Processing.
Libraries exist such as `spacy` and `nltk` that support tokenization, lemmatization and stemming.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use this function, I tried this, it removes all the special characters (All non letters/digits) and punctuations and gets the statement to lower case letters

```
import re
def word_normalizer(word): 
    word = re.sub('[^A-Za-z0-9]+', '', word)
    return word.lower()
```

Comment: better tell the exact stuff that are replaced : all non letter/digit

Comment: It will also remove any accented or non-ascii characters like `ö` for example.

Answer (score 0):

The standard *string* module has a useful *punctuation* value (which may or may not be suitable for your purposes).

You could conveniently use the *re* module to handle the replacements.

The following code removes trailing 's' which may not be desirable for all cases - i.e., just because a word ends with 's' doesn't necessarily mean that it's plural

Some replacements will result in duplication so use a set.

```
import string
import re

punc = re.compile(f'[{string.punctuation}]')
word_list = ["Alzheimer", "Alzheimer's", "Alzheimer.", "Alzheimer?","Cognition.", "Cognition's", "Cognitions", "Cognition"]
new_word_set = {punc.sub('', word).rstrip('s') for word in word_list}

print(new_word_set)
```

**Output:**

```
{'Alzheimer', 'Cognition'}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use functional techniques to do this pretty concisely

```py
    from functools import reduce

  punctuation = ["'", '"', ";", ":", ",", ".", "&", "(", ")"]
  words =  ["Alzheimer", "Alzheimer's", "Alzheimer.", "Alzheimer?","Cognition.", "Cognition's", "Cognitions", "Cognition"]

  # remove a character from a string
  def strip_punc(word: str, character_to_strip: str) -> str:
    return word.replace(character_to_strip, "")

  # run the strip_punc function for each item in the punctuation list
  def clean_word(word: str): list(str) -> list(str):
    return reduce(strip_punc, punctuation, word)

  # run the clean_word function on each word in the word list
  # use set to remove dupes
  return set(map(clean_word, words))
```

You can use lambda functions to make this even more concise

```py
  from functools import reduce

  punctuation = ["'", '"', ";", ":", ",", ".", "&", "(", ")"]
  words =  ["Alzheimer", "Alzheimer's", "Alzheimer.", "Alzheimer?","Cognition.", "Cognition's", "Cognitions", "Cognition"]

  return set(
    map(
     lambda p: reduce(lambda p, w: p.replace(w, ""), punctuation, p), words
    )
  )
```